# I need to add 3 hours to a date + a time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column where each cell has a date and a time in it

4/12/14 8:35 PM

I want to add 3 hours to the time for each cell.

In the end, it will be: 4/12/14 11:35 PM

What's the quickest way to do this?

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but didnt keep the date. How do I include this as well?

Comment: use cell formatting to display full date and time

Answer (score 2):

1. consider =A1+3/24  *-– simoco*
2. use cell formatting to display full date and time *-- nazim*

Comment: Another option is like this: `=A1+"3:00"` - that's possibly simpler should you want to add a value like `3:25`......or for time values under 24 hours use TIME function like `=A1+TIME(3,0,0)`